# visual Unhandled exception in Debugger::HandleIPCEvent when breaking on certain breakpoint

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I get the following exception (in Dutch, English translation follows in the text) which breaks my debugger when I press 'OK' it stops the debug session and closes the application:

[image]

Translated in text:

```
---------------------------
LerTemperaturaWPF.vshost.exe - Application Error
---------------------------
INTERNAL ERROR:
Unhandled exception in Debugger::HandleIPCEvent.
Event ID=0x246.
Exception code=0xc0000005, Eip=0x68fbaeca.
Process ID=0x1094 (4244), Thread ID=0x10a4 (4260).
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

This happens if the first time the debugger breaks are inside a certain piece of code:

```
private void PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Set value of property, only when the long editor is selected (no optionlist item is selected)
    if (this.Editor.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        if (this.Editor.SelectedItem as OptionForList == null)
        {
            this.Editor.SelectedValue = ((Management.Property)this.Editor.SelectedItem).Value;
            this.Editor.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

It happens when I place the breakpoint inside the 2nd if statement, before the second if statement (where ever I place it). It gives me no problems.

If I make sure the first break the debugger has is before this code and afterward it hits a breakpoint in this code there are no problems either. The debugger must have broken before getting to this code. Now I do not think it has anything to do with this code (90% certain).

The property changed is a user control and somehow I think the debugger can't handle the user control properly? maybe?

Has anyone seen this behavior before and know how to fix this? do I need to turn off (or on) some of the debug settings??

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Right click on the project/solution -> Properties -> Debug -> Check "Enable native code debugging".

Comment: This worked for me. In my case the breakpoint was on an async method. Would be nice to know why this happen.

Comment: For me, It worked because I was trying to debug an application and it was breaking everytime I hover over a custom control variable which was inherited from Textbox so I was just checking various configurations in Debug settings and this one worked for me.

Comment: Worked like a magic! Since, there is no C or pointer (native code) in my project.

Answer (score 2):

(1) On the Debug menu->Windows->Exceptions, and enable all Thrown check boxes. Debug the application, it will show you the actual and detailed errors in a message Box.

(2) Right click on the project/solution -> Properties -> Debug -> Uncheck "Enable visual studio hosting process".

(3) Please also change the Platform target (X86/Any CPU/X64), re-compile the app, debug it again.

(4)Tools > Options > Debugging > General > "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" checkbox.

Comment: Do you get the same error messages? Can you share a sample?

Comment: I was debugging a WPF program, and had a breakpoint added to an Clicked event of a button. There was nothing useful in that event yet: the breakpoint was added to the opening bracket.

Comment: Is it related to the specific code line in your side? For the unhandled exception issue, you really need to collect the detailed error messages and analyze the parameters in detail in your side if you couldn't provide the sample.

Comment: No it's not: the opening bracket was the only thing on that line... :) I just circumvented it

Answer (score 0):

All answers described here do not guarantee 100% cure. What I am doing as a workaround is that **just stepping over to the next line while debugging**.After that I can see the value of that variable in the watch on mouse hover. (In my case, stepping over to next line does not change value)